# Image editor that can be initialized with image that retrieved form DB

Tags: java, image, jsp

I save the image in db as blob and I want to allow the user to edit the image (rotate,zoom in /out actions are required).

I'm looking for a tool that can be initialized with image (that retrieved form DB  ,I assume that I'll need to calculate the bytes here)

- the image isn't saved in server / client side.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[JIU - Java Imaging Utilities](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jiu/?source=navbar)

you can use this source code.
I would suggest write the image to a temporary path and then do what ever you want to do.